# How to add aggregated data to the original dataset in Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, scalability

I am trying to figure out how to aggregate data from a dataset and then add the result to the original dataset using Apache Spark.
I have tried 2 solutions that I'm not satisfied with, and I wonder if there's a more scalable and efficient solution that I'm not seeing.

Here are very simplified samples of input and expected output data:

**Input**:

A list of customers, and for each customer, a list of purchased items.

```
(John, [toast, butter])
(Jane, [toast, jelly])
```

**Output**:

A list of customers, and for each customer, a list of purchased items, and for each item, the number of customers who purchased this item.

```
(John, [(toast, 2), (butter, 1)])
(Jane, [(toast, 2), (jelly, 1)])
```

---

Here are the solutions I've tried so far, listing steps and output data.

**Solution #1:**

```
Start with a pair rdd:
(John, [toast, butter])
(Jane, [toast, jelly])

flatMapToPair:
(toast, John)
(butter, John)
(toast, Jane)
(jelly, Jane)

aggregateByKey: 
(toast, [John, Jane])
(butter, [John])
(jelly, [Jane])

flatMapToPair: (using the size of the list of customers)
(John, [(toast, 2), (butter, 1)])
(Jane, [(toast, 2), (jelly, 1)])
```

While this works for a small dataset, it's a terrible idea with a larger one because at one point you hold for each product a huge list of customers that probably won't fit in the executor's memory.

**Solution #2:**

```
Start with a pair rdd:
(John, [toast, butter])
(Jane, [toast, jelly])

flatMapToPair:
(toast, John)
(butter, John)
(toast, Jane)
(jelly, Jane)

aggregateByKey: (counting customers without creating a list)
(toast, 2)
(butter, 1)
(jelly, 1)

join: (using the two previous results)
(toast, (John, 2))
(butter, (John, 1))
(toast, (Jane, 2))
(jelly, (Jane, 1))

mapToPair:
(John, (toast, 2))
(John, (butter, 1))
(Jane, (toast, 2))
(Jane, (jelly, 1))

aggregateByKey:
(John, [(toast, 2), (butter, 1)])
(Jane, [(toast, 2), (jelly, 1)])
```

This solution should work, but I feel like there should be some other solution that might not involve joining RDDs.

**Is there a more scalable/efficient/better "Solution #3" to this problem?**

Answer (score 1):

I thing another approach would be to use GraphX.

Here is working code (scala 2.11.12, Spark 2.3.0):

```
import org.apache.spark.graphx._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object Main {

  private val ss = SparkSession.builder().appName("").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
  private val sc = ss.sparkContext

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")

    // Class for vertex values
    case class Value(name: String, names: List[String], count: Int)
    // Message that is sent from one Vertex to another
    case class Message(names: List[String], count: Int)

    // Simulate input data
    val allData = sc.parallelize(Seq(
      ("John", Seq("toast", "butter")),
      ("Jane", Seq("toast", "jelly"))
    ))

    // Create vertices
    // Goods and People names - all will become vertices
    val vertices = allData.flatMap(pair =>
      pair._2 // Take all goods bought
        .union(Seq(pair._1)) // add name
        .map(v => (v.hashCode.toLong, Value(v, List[String](), 0)))) // (id, Value)

    // Hash codes are required because in GraphX in vertexes requires IDs as Long
    // Create edges: Person --> Bought goods
    val edges = allData
      .flatMap(pair =>
        pair._2 // Take all goods
          .map(goods => Edge[Int](pair._1.hashCode().toLong, goods.hashCode.toLong, 0))) // create pairs of (person, bought_good)

    // Create graph from edges and vertices
    val graph = Graph(vertices, edges)

    // Initial message will be sent to all vertexes at the start
    val initialMsg = Message(List[String](), 0)

    // How vertex should process received message
    def onMsgReceive(vertexId: VertexId, value: Value, msg: Message): Value = {
      if (msg == initialMsg) value // Just ignore initial message
      else Value(value.name, msg.names, msg.count) // Received message already contains all our results
    }

    // How vertexes should send messages
    def sendMsg(triplet: EdgeTriplet[Value, Int]): Iterator[(VertexId, Message)] = {
      // Each vertix sends only one message with it's own name and 1
      Iterator((triplet.dstId, Message(List[String](triplet.srcAttr.name), 1)))
    }

    // How incoming messages to one vertex should be merged
    def mergeMsg(msg1: Message, msg2: Message): Message = {
      // On the goods vertices messages from people who bought them will merge
      // Final message will contain names of all people who bought this good and count of them
      Message(msg1.names ::: msg2.names, msg1.count + msg2.count)
    }

    // Kick out pregel calculation
    val res = graph
      .pregel(initialMsg, Int.MaxValue, EdgeDirection.Out)(onMsgReceive, sendMsg, mergeMsg)

    val values = res.vertices
      .filter(v => v._2.count != 0)   // Filter out people - they will not have any incoming edges
      .map(pair => pair._2)           // Also remove IDs

    values      // (good, (List of names, count))
      .flatMap(v => v.names.map(n => (n, (v.name, v.count))))     // transform to (name, (good, count))
      .aggregateByKey(List[(String, Int)]())((acc, v) => v :: acc, (acc1, acc2) => acc1 ::: acc2)   // aggregate by names
      .collect().foreach(println)     // Print the result
  }
}
```

Probably there is better way how to do it with same approach, but still - the result:

```
=======================================
(Jane,List((jelly,1), (toast,2)))
(John,List((butter,1), (toast,2)))
```

### **UPDATE**

This second example is what i was talking about in comments.

```
import org.apache.spark.graphx._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object Main {

  private val ss = SparkSession.builder().appName("").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
  private val sc = ss.sparkContext

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")

    // Entity and how much it was bought
    case class Entity(name: String, bought: Int)
    // Class for vertex values
    case class Value(name: Entity, names: List[Entity])
    // Message that is sent from one Vertex to another
    case class Message(items: List[Entity])
    // Simulate input data
    val allData = sc.parallelize(Seq(
      ("John", Seq("toast", "butter")),
      ("Jane", Seq("toast", "jelly"))
    ))

    // First calculate how much of each Entity was bought
    val counts = allData
      .flatMap(pair => pair._2.map(v => (v, 1))) // flatten all bought items
      .reduceByKey(_ + _) // count occurrences
      .map(v => Entity(v._1, v._2)) // create items

    // Create vertices
    // Goods and People names - all will become vertices
    val vertices = allData
      .map(pair => Entity(pair._1, 0))    // People are also Entities - but with 0, since they were not bought :)
      .union(counts)                      //
      .map(v => (v.name.hashCode.toLong, Value(Entity(v.name, v.bought), List[Entity]())))      // (key, value)

    // Hash codes are required because in GraphX in vertexes requires IDs as Long
    // Create edges: Entity --> Person
    val edges = allData
      .flatMap(pair =>
        pair._2 // Take all goods
          .map(goods => Edge[Int](goods.hashCode.toLong, pair._1.hashCode().toLong, 0)))

    // Create graph from edges and vertices
    val graph = Graph(vertices, edges)

    // Initial message will be sent to all vertexes at the start
    val initialMsg = Message(List[Entity](Entity("", 0)))

    // How vertex should process received message
    def onMsgReceive(vertexId: VertexId, value: Value, msg: Message): Value = {
      if (msg == initialMsg) value // Just ignore initial message
      else Value(value.name, msg.items) // Received message already contains all results
    }

    // How vertexes should send messages
    def sendMsg(triplet: EdgeTriplet[Value, Int]): Iterator[(VertexId, Message)] = {
      // Each vertex sends only one message with it's own Entity
      Iterator((triplet.dstId, Message(List[Entity](triplet.srcAttr.name))))
    }

    // How incoming messages to one vertex should be merged
    def mergeMsg(msg1: Message, msg2: Message): Message = {
      // On the goods vertices messages from people who bought them will merge
      // Final message will contain names of all people who bought this good and count of them
      Message(msg1.items ::: msg2.items)
    }

    // Kick out pregel calculation
    val res = graph
      .pregel(initialMsg, Int.MaxValue, EdgeDirection.Out)(onMsgReceive, sendMsg, mergeMsg)


    res
      .vertices
      .filter(vertex => vertex._2.names.nonEmpty)             // Filter persons
      .map(vertex => (vertex._2.name.name, vertex._2.names))  // Remove vertex IDs
      .collect()      // Print results
      .foreach(println)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for having spent some time on this. Currently, I'm unfamiliar with Scala (I use Java) and I've never used the GraphX API. From my understanding of your code, particularly `Message(msg1.names ::: msg2.names, msg1.count + msg2.count)` and `// (good, (List of names, count))`, it seems like you are building a list of customer names for each item/good. Is your solution more scalable than Solution #1 described in my question?

Comment: I think you're right - my solution might have same weakness as #1. But anyway i just tried to show the idea. Probably it's possible to make my solution better by creating edges from goods to people. This way messages will be sent to people and there you can get the result without building the list of people per product.

Comment: @ThomasW i've updated my answer and added example that avoids keeping the list of names per person - as i've told in previous comment.

Comment: To be hones, I'm not aware how exactly GraphX works internally, so it's quite possible, that underneath there are joins or whatever you've tried to avoid. :)

Comment: I like your update, I'm curious to know what happens under the hood as well. For now, I'm still trying to find a solution that doesn't involve rewriting chunks of code with GraphX, because my real-life use case isn't as simple as the example in my question ;). But I'll keep you posted as soon as I've tried your GraphX solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `dataframe` way for you to try and play with

If you already have a paired *rdds* then calling a `toDF` with column names should give you a `dataframe` as

```
val df = pairedRDD.toDF("key", "value")
```

which should be

```
+----+---------------+
|key |value          |
+----+---------------+
|John|[toast, butter]|
|Jane|[toast, jelly] |
+----+---------------+
```

Now all you have to do is `explode`, `groupby`, *aggregation for the counts* and again `explode`, `groupby` and *aggregation to get the original dataset with counts* as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.withColumn("value", explode(col("value")))
  .groupBy("value").agg(count("value").as("count"), collect_list("key").as("key"))
  .withColumn("key", explode(col("key")))
  .groupBy("key").agg(collect_list(struct("value", "count")).as("value"))
```

which should give you

```
+----+-----------------------+
|key |value                  |
+----+-----------------------+
|John|[[toast,2], [butter,1]]|
|Jane|[[jelly,1], [toast,2]] |
+----+-----------------------+
```

You can process further in `dataframe` or change back to `rdd` by using `.rdd` api.

Comment: Thanks for your example. However, If we run this on a big dataset, won't `collect_list("key").as("key")` create a field that contains a huge list of people for each `value`, just like Solution #1 in my question?

Comment: Did you try it? if the grouping key has large dataset, yes you are correct. But thats what your requirement is. and if you don't want to collect then join is the way as you've already done it in rdd. You can try join in dataframe way too. I am suggesting dataframes or datasets as they are the optimized form of rdd.