# (Spark skewed join) How to join two large Spark RDDs with highly duplicated keys without memory issues?

Tags: java, apache-spark, join, rdd, scalability

In [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50526052/), I was trying to **avoid memory issues** with Spark `join` by avoiding using `join`.

In this new question, I'm using `join`, but trying to **fix memory issues** with it.

These are my two RDDs:

1. productToCustomerRDD:
   Size: very large, could have millions of distinct keys
   Partitioned on keys with a `HashPartitioner`
   Some keys will be **highly** duplicated and some won't.

   ```
   (toast, John)
   (butter, John)
   (toast, Jane)
   (jelly, Jane)
   ```
2. productToCountRDD:
   Size: very large, could have millions of distinct keys, too big to `broadcast`
   Partitioned on keys with a `HashPartitioner`
   Keys are **unique**, the value is the number of customers who've purchased the product.

   ```
   (toast, 2)
   (butter, 1)
   (jelly, 1)
   ```

I would like to join these two RDDs, the result will be:

3. customerToProductAndCountRDD:

   ```
   (toast, (John, 2))
   (butter, (John, 1))
   (toast, (Jane, 2))
   (jelly, (Jane, 1))
   ```

If I join the two RDDs with `productToCustomerRDD.join(productToCountRDD)` I get an `OutOfMemoryError` on two partitions (out of thousands). In the Spark UI, I've noticed that during the stage that contains the `join`, in the `Input Size / Records` column, all partitions have a number of records from **4K** to **700K**. All except the two partitions that produced the OOM: one has **9M** records and one has **6M** records.

As I understand, *in order to join, pairs with the same key need to be shuffled and moved to the same partition* (unless they were previously partitioned by key). However, since some keys are very frequent (for instance: a product that was purchased by nearly every single customer in the dataset), a huge amount of data may be moved to one partition, either during the `join` or during the `repartition` right before the join.

Am I understanding this correctly?
Is there a way to avoid this?
Could there be a way to `join` without having all the data for one heavily duplicated key on the same partition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, this is a standard problem in Spark called "skewed join": one of the sides of the join is skewed, meaning some of its keys are much more frequent that others. Some answers that didn't work out for me can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38960599/apache-spark-handling-skewed-data).

The strategy I used is inspired by the `GraphFrame.skewedJoin()` method defined [here](https://github.com/graphframes/graphframes/blob/cb0d8371b6f96032aaa4e23c0f34bfb5c8aeca55/src/main/scala/org/graphframes/GraphFrame.scala#L597) and its use in `ConnectedComponents.skewedJoin()` [here](https://github.com/graphframes/graphframes/blob/cb0d8371b6f96032aaa4e23c0f34bfb5c8aeca55/src/main/scala/org/graphframes/lib/ConnectedComponents.scala#L241).
The join will be performed by joining the most frequent keys using a broadcast join and the less frequent keys using a standard join.

In my example (OP) the `productToCountRDD` already contains the information about key frequency.
So it goes like this:

- Filter `productToCountRDD` to only keep counts that are above a fixed threshold, and `collectAsMap()` to the driver.
- Broadcast this map to all executors.
- Split `productToCustomerRDD` into two RDDs: keys that are found in the broadcast map (frequent keys), and keys that aren't (infrequent keys).
- The join for frequent keys is performed with `mapToPair`, getting the `count` from the broadcast map
- The join for infrequent keys is performed with `join`.
- Use `union` at the end to get your full RDD.

Answer (score 0):

my first question is: Do you really need theese detailed data? Do you really need to know that jhon bought 2 toats and so on? We are in big data context and we work with a lot of data so sometimes aggregation is a good thing to reduce cardinality and obtain good results in terms of analysis and performance. So if you want to know how many times a product was sold you can use a pairRDD(product, count) [in this way you will have one element for each product] or if you want to know users preferences you can use a pairRDD(user, list of purchased products) [in this way you will have an element for each user]. If you really need to know that a toast was bought from Jhon why you want to split the toast key in different repartitions? In this way you can't compute a global result because in every chunck you will have only a piece of information about your keys.